# How to handle 302 in django 2.2?

Tags: django, python-3.x, redirect, httprequest

I have 3 or more items in my order summary page. When I remove one of the items, my code redirects me to the same order summary page. But when I am trying to remove last order from the order summary page, my code redirects me to the home page.

> I want to stay on the same page while the cart is empty with continue
>   shopping button but when I removed the last item from the cart it
>   redirects me back to home page

views.py

```
def remove_from_cart(request, slug):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
    cart_qs = Cart.objects.filter(item=course, user=request.user)
    if cart_qs.exists():
        # cart = cart_qs[0]
        # if cart.quantity > 1:
        #     cart.quantity -= 1
        #     cart.save()
        # else:
        cart_qs.delete()
        order_qs = Order.objects.filter(
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False
        )
        if order_qs.exists():
            order = order_qs[0]
            # check if the order item is in the order
            if order.orderitems.filter(item__slug=course.slug).exists():
                order_item = Cart.objects.filter(
                    course=course,
                    user=request.user,
                )[0]
                order.orderitems.remove(order_item)
                messages.info(request, "This item was removed from your cart.")
                return redirect("cart:order-summary")
            else:
                messages.info(request, "This item was not in your cart")
                return redirect("cart:order-summary")
    else:
        messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order")
        return redirect("cart:order-summary")
```

order-summary.html

```
<tbody>
                        {% if carts %}
                        {% for cart in carts %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{ cart.item }}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Rs. {{ cart.price }}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Rs. {{cart.get_total }}</p>
                                    <a href="{% url 'cart:remove-from-cart' cart.item.slug %}">Remove</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Your Cart is Empty </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        {% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
   app_name= 'cart'

    urlpatterns = [
        # path('', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
        path('<slug>', add_to_cart, name='cart'),
        path('remove/<slug>', remove_from_cart, name='remove-from-cart'),
        path('order-summary/', CartView, name='order-summary'),
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: Show your urls.py

Comment: @Charnel I have added urls.py

Comment: What if you replace the redirect with this `redirect("order-summary")`, does it works?

Comment: @Charnel it shows me NoReverseMatch error. it i do that

Comment: Hm, can you show the code of `CartView`?

Comment: @Charnel Thank You. In CartView I have used redirect() instead render().

Comment: Your welcome! If my advice was useful - please rate up my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have used redirect() instead of render().

```
def CartView(request):
    user = request.user
    # course = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
    carts = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
    orders = Order.objects.filter(user=user, ordered=False)

    if carts.exists():
        order = orders[0]
        return render(request, 'order-summary.html', {"carts": carts, 'order': order})

    else:
        messages.warning(request, "You do not have an active order")
        # return redirect("cart:order-summary")
        return render(request, 'order-summary.html')
```